# WinForms WebBrowser - will it still work after IE retirement?

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I am using the `WebBrowser` control in a Windows desktop application. Will it be affected by the retirement of Internet Explorer on June 15, 2022?

Comment: You mean 2022, not 2021!

Answer (score 5):

According to this [official blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549), IE engine MSHTML (Trident) will continue to be supported. The retirement will only affect Internet Explorer 11 desktop application, WebBrowser control will still work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FYI the WebBrowser control is being considered for obsoletion .NET7 and beyond. https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/6964

Comment: If you disagree with the change, make sure to express your opinion on the GitHub issue page.